# How do you manipulate GOD without actually cheating?

Tags: x3-terran-conflict

I got the problem in my game that GOD deletes a lot of factories which produce guns. So far I blame my defensive and peaceful gameplay as a trader and manufacturer. But atm I am on the hub plot and it involves a lot of producing and managing, so not much time for combat.

Anyway, I bought 2 Boreas and now I got serious trouble outfitting them with Clusterflak Artillery, because GOD in his wisdom decided to delete all of them but 1. I have built my own complex producing them, but it takes a long time and 1 Boreas needs around 36 Artillery Guns for a full loadout.

**So my question is, how do you stop GOD from deleting more gun related factories and can I animate him to rebuild some of them?**

Comment: There's *got* to be a way to phrase this question title to make it even more theologically interesting.

Comment: Why all the downvoting?

Comment: Maybe people aren't sure why you are calling the engine god.  Just for clarification the in game engine that adds and removes stations is called the god engine for some reason even though the full term is global decision engine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the only cases I know of where factories won't be removed randomly:

1. If you park one of your ships there, it will never be deleted.
2. If the factory turns a profit, it won't be removed.

For #2, you'll have to keep the factories stocked up with the raw supplies it needs to make items.

Finally, rather than relying and hoping that the game makes more factories, its easier for you to either take station building missions or build your own factories.  As far as I can tell, stations you place via build missions are never randomly removed.

One last note, the cluster flak artillery is rather bad (there's a glitch in TC where they miss all the time) as anti-fighter defense.  You'll want the Teladi version called Flak Artillery arrays instead.  This may have been patched since its been a few months since I played but I haven't seen anything about them in update notes.  And I can't think of a reason why you would want so many of them anyway on a Boreas since they aren't anti capital ship weapons.